# How To Skip PaperTrail Version on ActiveRecord Callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, paper-trail-gem

Currently, I've implemented a Rails Data Auditing app using PaperTrail.
I've added a new version for every `create`, `update` and `destroy` actions.

The thing is that, I have an `after_create` callback in my model in which I want the PaperTrail to ignore it.

For now, when I create a new record, there are two versions are created. One is of the create event, and other one is of the update event of my callback.

What I want is to just one version to be created here, a version of the create event.

To be specific, my callback is just to add a slug, an alias is, to my record in which I do not want to show such this change to the user.

I wonder if there is a way to do so.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: you could use `before_create` instead I think.

Comment: Thank @AndreyDeineko for first and fast response. However, I'm sorry to tell that I cannot use before_create in my case since I use the ID of the record to form an alias ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can make use of [`without_versioning`](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/blob/c37e48973d8006edf635c72d5c742ce2d76c2f25/lib/paper_trail/record_trail.rb#L383), which

> Executes the given method or block without creating a new version

```
user.without_versioning { |obj| obj.update_attributes(attribute: 'new_value') }
```

Comment: @PirunSeng great, glad to help! Make sure to accept answers, that worked for you (I just noticed, you don't usually do that) - look for a checkmark near the answer's score :)

Comment: @PirunSeng thx. Also, check out your previous questions - may there are also answers which deserve a checkmark? This way you notify the community this particular issue is solved.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about my previous questions. Anyway, I just want to add another note for your answer. I've just come up with the PaperTrail deprecation warning running rspec. `DEPRECATION WARNING: Use paper_trail.without_versioning instead of without_versioning.` I've updated that line and it still works just fine and the warning has gone :)

Answer (score 6):

`without_versioning` was removed in v10, as mentionned [here](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail#per-method-removed).

Use instead :

```rb
PaperTrail.request(enabled: false) do
  # no versions created
end
```

Or for specific model only :

```rb
PaperTrail.request.disable_model(Banana)
# changes to Banana model do not create versions,
# but eg. changes to Kiwi model do.
PaperTrail.request.enable_model(Banana)
```